# Downloading one drive file given a link in a single api call

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

I have an attachment link which points to user's onedrive .

> https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/drive_name/Documents/Microsoft
>   Teams Chat Files/hr.pak

While I can download this file by following series of steps:

1. Getting user's driveid

> GET
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{idOrUserPrincipalName}/drive

2. Get items from the root drive

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root/children

3. Get items of Microsoft Team Chat Files folder

> GET
>   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/children

4. Download file using the value of @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl field.

Is it possible to translate the url(https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/drive_name/Documents/Microsoft Teams Chat Files/hr.pak) to a single graph api call to download the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/DRIVE_ID/root:/FILE_PATH/hr.pak:/content

replace the words in CAPS with your details.